# Creating orderable list in WPF using ListBox (HOWTO or better approach?)

Tags: wpf, listbox

I've got a list of things that I want the user to easily edit the order of. Right now I'm binding them to a ListBox with a custom ItemTemplate. Within that template I have an UP & DOWN button. My goal was to move the item up/down based on the button clicked.

However I'm having trouble associating the button's click event with the actual item in the list. I've seen some folks setup a drag/drop for ordering items but that that would be too complex for this app (it's target user base =1, just me).

I assume this is possible with a ListBox. Maybe someone has a beter idea on how to implement this? It's not a huge set of data... less than 25 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataContext of the button (of the entire template, thus inherited by the button) is the item itself. Simply cast it to your desired type.